# windows XP not supporting TLSv1.2

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2012, openssl, tls1.2, sslv3

currently i am working on something which requires my client to connect to host server using TLSv1.2 in windows xp environment. i have built my application dll with openssl static library and using the same openssl dll's to invoke my client sample application. i am using visual studio 2012 for building. the dll is working perfectly fine with windows 7 environment, but its not working with windows xp. below are the things i have tried and explored till now.

1) in visual studio, project properties, we can select the environment for which we want to build. i have selected the same for windows xp. 
[visual studio properties for windows xp build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsDzG.jpg)

2) i am using openssl v1.0.2j which supports TLS v1.2 for building my application dll.

3) in my dll code i made changes for initializing ctx to tlsv1_2_method().

4) my client application which invokes the application dll which is built using visual studio is running on windows xp. the host server uses TLSv1.2 protocol for communication. so my client application should communicate using TLSv1.2 and that is where the problem is i guess. if i am using sslv3, its working fine.

if i used sslv3_method() in my code and build with the same settings, i am able to call my dll from sample application in xp and its working fine. but when i use tlsv1_2_method(), it does not work its giving error, my.dll not found.

i have added all the required supported libraries and checked with dependency walker software. there are not dependent dll's missing.

i googled for the above issue, and found that windows xp does not support TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2. but i also found out if we are not using windows protocol communication mechanism and our own communication application, then it can be done. but i dont have resource nor required in-depth knowledge to do so.

Is there any method or steps to build openssl library for windows xp seperately?

it would be of great help if you can anyone can tell me if there is a way through which this can be done. whether i need to build openssl libraries for windows xp in some other way or is there any setting which i am missing. below are the links which i went through for getting info on this issue.

[support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows](http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/)

please guide me on how i can make tlsv1.2 work on windows xp.

Comment: It's not fully clear but it sounds like the server is using Windows XP but you talk about the client application. To have TLS 1.2 both server and client need to support this protocol which should be possible if both use a current version of OpenSSL as TLS stack but not if one of these uses the XP TLS stack.

Comment: I think you need to delete most of the question's existing text. The best I can tell, its mostly irrelevant. Then, show the code you are using that works, and then show the same code with the changes that do not work. Finally, provide a copy/paste of the exact error message.